# Evitar que me cambie los datos al pasar a valor numerico una columna

Tags: r

Tengo una tabla de datos con un valor que quiero pasar a numérico, pero al poner

```
var.graph.entrada$count<-as.numeric(var.graph.entrada$count)
```

me cambia los valores de la columna.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para pasar los valores como numéricos y que no me cambie los datos?

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
var.graph.entrada$count<-as.numeric(var.graph.entrada$count)
```

Comment: Por favor brinda una muestra de cómo lucen tus datos antes y después de lo que intentaste. De preferencia que sea el resultado que obtienes en la consola copiado y pegado

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: ¿Qué significa "que me cambia los datos"?  agrega por favor la salida de `str(var.graph.entrada)`

Comment: Me imagino que `count` debe ser factor. Se soluciona con `as.numeric(as.character(var.graph.entrada$count))`. Pero sube el resultado de `str` como Patricio lo indica